# Win7 BSOD after user rebooted laptop while installing Windows update

Tags: windows-7, windows

c000021a 0xc000012f is the BSOD.

http://pastebin.com/EtVDdSPW
Contains the WindowsUpdate.log

Booted up using Windows 7 CD and going into Repair.
I've ran sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=c:\windows about 4-5 times already as suggested from google search.

This is the CBS.log http://pastebin.com/L91aLHsi

I've ran chkdsk /f /x /r and came back with minor bitmap errors.

Tried uninstalling the Windows update via wusa /uninstall kb:xxxxx on the patches but it isn't letting me.

Windows 7 doesn't seem to be like XP where you can just put the CD and run a repair install. It seems that you need to be able to boot into the OS then run a repair. Unfortunately I can't boot into OS as I get BSOD on bootup. Tried safe mode/ last known configs.

edit: forgot to mention system restore is disabled so I can't revert it.

Comment: the SxsStore.dll is missing, so all serving operations won't work. If you have a second PC, copy the file SxsStore.dll to an USB device and copy it to the System32 folder of your damaged Windows. MAybe this helps. If not, you're SOL and you have to reinstall.

Comment: I've got several PC with identical Win7 Pro 32bit. Copied over the sxsstore.dll from an identical PC but still complains the same error. Something I notice is that it puts the CBS.log into x:\windows\logs\CBS\CBS.log rather than in c:\ I'm thinking whether it ran a repair on C rather than X. If I don't specify the additional offboot then it doesn't generate any cbs.log Any idea? Normally I would just reimage the PC but this one is heavily customized and will take over a week to reinstall.

Comment: I have no real idea. Disabling system restore is not a good idea without having a good backup plan.